# How do I prevent a text stroke from cutting off at the edge of a UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, core-text, stroke

I'm adding a fairly wide stroke of a few pixels to text in a `UILabel`, and depending on the line spacing, if the very edges of the text touch the very edges of the label, the sides of the stroke can be cut off, if they go outside of the bounds of the label. **How can I prevent this?** Here's the code I'm using to apply the stroke (currently of 5px):

```
- (void) drawTextInRect: (CGRect) rect
{
    UIColor *textColor = self.textColor;

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 5);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(c, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke);
    self.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.165 green: 0.635 blue: 0.843 alpha: 1.0];
    [super drawTextInRect: rect];
}
```

Here's an example of the clipping at the side of the label, I think what needs to happen is one of the following:

- That when the text splits onto multiple lines, some space is given inside the label's frame for the stroke to occupy.
- Or, that the stroke is allowed to overflow the outer bounds of the label.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what about to use `[_yourLabel setClipsToBounds:NO];`? ...you could try to set it for the label's superview as well if there is any.

Comment: @holex Nope, already tried that I'm afraid, has no effect at all. I've also tried `masksToBounds` on the layer, and tried it on all superviews.

Comment: how does you view hierarchy look?

Comment: @holex The label itself, which is of type `OutlineLabel`, which is a `UILabel` subclass which only overrides the method shown above, which is directly in the main view of the `ViewController`. Nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, clipping just didn't work.

What if you create insets on your `UILabel` sub-class though. You'd make the frame of the label however big you need it to be, then set your insets. When you draw the text, it will use the insets to give you padding around any edge you need.

The downside is, you won't be able to judge line wrapping at a glance in IB. You'd have to take your label and subtract your insets then you'll see what it would really look line on the screen.

.h

```
@interface MyLabel : UILabel
@property (nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets insets;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyLabel

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 3, 0, 3);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(c);

    CGRect actualTextContentRect = rect;
    actualTextContentRect.origin.x += self.insets.left;
    actualTextContentRect.origin.y += self.insets.top;
    actualTextContentRect.size.width -= self.insets.right;
    actualTextContentRect.size.height -= self.insets.bottom;

    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 5);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(c, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke);
    self.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.165 green: 0.635 blue: 0.843 alpha: 1.0];

    [super drawTextInRect:actualTextContentRect];
    CGContextRestoreGState(c);
    self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [super drawTextInRect:actualTextContentRect];
}
```

[image: Simulator run]

**Edit:** Added full code for my `UILabel` subclass. Modified the code slightly to show both the large stroke and the the normal lettering.

Comment: this seems to have made things worse! The edges are still clipping in the same place, but by doing this, all of the text seems to get written twice, once at the original location and once at the insets!

Comment: I updated the code to show a more complete version of the code. It now shows drawing of the text with the large stroke and the normal looking drawn text also. So I am am writing text twice, but both should use the offset.

Comment: This didn't work either. Set your line width to 50 or something and you'll see it's still being cut off. Certainly is here anyway, exactly like the image above, still. I completely removed everything in my subclass and used yours with no changes, so I'm not sure why it's not happening. My `UILabel` is not the full width of the view in question, and I'd like the stroke to spill out into that extra width.

Comment: I added a second image (lighter blue stroke) – that's what I'm seeing with your code here.

Comment: The size of your insets has to be based on the size of your stroke. If your stroke is still getting clipped you need to make the inset larger. The label also has to be larger to account for the extra space, the insets won't prevent clipping, but it will allow you increase the size of the label to account for the stroke without worrying about spacing issues.

Comment: Looks like it's working! Not perfect, and kind of a skirt, but worth the bounty I'd say!

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `sizeThatFits:` on your `UILabel` subclass to return a slightly larger preferred size, taking the additional space required for the stroke into consideration. You can then either use the result of `sizeThatFits:` to calculate the label's frame correctly, or just call `sizeToFit`.

Comment: That's a little bit of a hassle, it has an `NSAttributedString` in it and is centered in the view, so using `sizeToFit` would mean having to re-position it, which may be tricky. Would there be another way to do it?

Comment: You could try setting `clipsToBounds` to NO to allow drawing outside the bounds of the label.

Comment: That didn't work, which is odd as I expected that it would. I've attached an image showing what I'm seeing.

Comment: In that case, I would still recommend you implement sizeThatFits: in order to help you calculate a larger frame/size for the label which you can then center. It should be as simple as taking `[super sizeThatFits:size]` and returning a width with the appropriate number of points added for the stroke on the left/right.

Comment: I've just realized even adjusting the frame may not be the perfect solution because it may cause the line wrapping to change and again cause clipping at the new width.

Comment: From another question, try `label.clipsToBounds = NO;` and `label.layer.masksToBounds = NO;`

Comment: Nope, no joy, still clipping. Just to confirm, I'm trying these both before and after I set the text in the label.